# Microsoft Graph SDK .NET - get users with managers and extra fields

Tags: .net, .net-core, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I want to get all graph users with their managers and some non-default fields in my ASP.NET Core 2.2 application. In order to do so, I wrote following code:

```
        graphServiceClient = new GraphServiceClient(new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(async request =>
        {
            request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", await tokenProvider.GetToken());
        }));

        var page = await graphServiceClient.Users
            .Request()
            .Expand(e => e.Manager)
            .Select(e => new
            {
                e.Department,
                e.OfficeLocation,
                e.JobTitle,
                e.UserPrincipalName,
                e.Mail,
                e.GivenName,
                e.DisplayName,
                e.Surname,
                e.MobilePhone,
                e.Id,
                e.EmployeeId
            })
            .GetAsync();
```

After this request for each user both **Manager** and **EmployeeId** fields are nulls. I am able to get these information directly from the API using /manager and /user endpoints with /?select=extension_88b64915d0de49799c8e36460702b34d_employeeNumber parameter with the same auth token, but I want to use SDK and make a single request.

How can I do this in one request with the SDK?

Answer (score 1):

I have been looking around for Microsoft Graph SDK classes and methods without much luck. Anyway if in your Microsoft Graph SDK classes and methods you have not found anything that does this for you in a single operation is because methods in SDKs and APIs are meant to have a single responsability (if a method gets the users it will not do anything else like get its managers). Also I read that the SDK is always a little behind the API current status and if you want to access latest functionality you should use an httpClient.

**Solution**: Implement your own method with the needed logic and fill the information that your need by using the currrent SDKs methods or by using httpClient to call the Graph API

I found a couple of examples that are probably familiar to you:
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer

Comment: Is there any way to get all users along with their managers in 1 request to Graph API? I know I can get all users and then manager for each one, but this is not an efficient solution.

Comment: To answer that i was looking of a complete list of the SDK methods (not the API) then with that you can browse arround and see if it is already there.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately retrieving users along with managers is not supported via a *single* request at the moment but the following approach could be considered instead:

a) submit a first request to retrieve users via [`List users` endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=cs)

b) construct and submit a [batch request](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/json-batching) to retrieve user's managers via [`List manager` endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-manager?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=cs):

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$batch
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "requests": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "method": "GET",
      "url": "/users/{id1 | userPrincipalName1}/manager"
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "method": "GET",
      "url": "/users/{id2 | userPrincipalName2}/manager"
    },
    //...
   ]
}
```

Here is an example for `msgraph-sdk-dotnet`:

```
//1. get user properties 
var users = await graphClient.Users
     .Request()
     .Select(e => new
                {
                    e.Department,
                    e.OfficeLocation,
                    e.JobTitle,
                    e.UserPrincipalName,
                    e.Mail,
                    e.GivenName,
                    e.DisplayName,
                    e.Surname,
                    e.MobilePhone,
                    e.Id,
                    e.EmployeeId
                })
      .GetAsync();


//2 get user's managers
var batchRequest = new BatchRequest();
foreach (var user in users)
{             
    batchRequest.AddQuery(graphClient.Users[user.UserPrincipalName].Manager.Request(), typeof(Microsoft.Graph.User));
}
var managers = await graphClient.GetBatchAsync(batchRequest);
foreach(var manager in managers)
{
   if (manager != null)
   {
       //...
   }
}
```

where [`BatchRequest class`](https://gist.github.com/vgrem/37dbe4762851decda79e32f5943b4fe3) is a custom class which implements support for JSON batching.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
 var users = await client.Users.Request()
                .Expand(u=>u.Manager)
                .Filter("accountEnabled eq true")
                .Select(u=>new 
                {
                    u.Id,
                    u.GivenName,
                    u.Surname,
                    u.DisplayName,
                    u.Mail,
                    u.JobTitle,
                    u.Department,
                    u.EmployeeId,
                    u.EmployeeType,
                    u.BusinessPhones,
                    u.MobilePhone,
                    u.Photo,
                    u.AccountEnabled,

                    u.Manager
                })
                .GetAsync();
```

Visit https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/create-requests?tabs=CS#use-expand-to-access-related-entities to see an example on using Expand to access related entities.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).